# LibGDX Change InputType to Number pad

Tags: java, eclipse, libgdx, android-inputtype

I just want to have a Number pad rather than a keyboard when I use 
`Gdx.input.getTextInput(TextInputListener,String,String)`

I added this to my android Manifest:
`android:inputType="number"`

But the full text keyboard still comes up. Anyone know how to change it?